pstricks's transparency not working (again)
The same question regarding pstricks's transparency was discussed in pgf's and pstricks's opacity is not working
Unfortunately, after upgrading to Texlive 2023 and Ghostscript 10.02.1, the same old issue we've discussed in this previous Q & A about pstricks's transparency appeared again.
Additionally, this time the changing of command in TexStudio from  ps2pdf %.ps %.pdf
to ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %.ps %.pdf
or ps2pdf -dNOSAFER %.ps %.pdf
doesn't solve the problem, as had happened before.
Any ideas?
Edit (23/12/2024): The issue related with XeTeX, which I'm using.

your example in the other question works fine for me in a current texlive 2024 with latex+dvips+pstopdf (and also in lualatex if I add \DocumentMetadata{} and remove the inputenc line).

@UlrikeFischer Thank you. I'm using XeTeX and TeXLive 2023, where this issue came up. Are you saying that with TeXLive 2024 there isn't such an issue? What about XeTeX?

@GrigoriosKostakos no where in your question is xelatex mentioned. You might want to fix that

with xelatex you need to use it with an option like `--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E". And sorry: but your question is then absolutely not the same as the one 6 year ago, which (because of the inputenc) clearly didn't use xetex.

@UlrikeFischer. Thank you. I apologize for the omission. I've already edited my question, adding that info.

Here is my entry in the preferences for commands->xelatex:

